# Forcing my activity to foreground?

Tags: android, asynchronous

I have a launcher style app. Once the user launches an app, a clock starts ticking and after a certain amount of time, the user is brought back to the main activity of my app and informed that time is up.

To achieve this, I have an AsyncTask whose doInBackground regularly checks how much time has elapsed (this part works fine). Then:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeScreenMain.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The only problem with this is that it keeps my app in the background, although I assume that the proper activity is launched. So my question is, how, when the time has expired, can I not only start this activity but bring it to the foreground on top of any app that the user may have launched from within my app?

Comment: Would you care to post your solution as an answer to your question (and possibly accept it as well) so others will see it as "answered". You might even get some upvotes ;-)

Comment: how about calling onResume? I bellieve it should bring the app in the foreground but I dont consider this to be a good idea since your app can pop up anytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing my original code with the following:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(HomeScreenMain.this, HomeScreenMain.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

Did the trick.